# Review before submitting?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible for someone who is submitting a multi-page form to review all of their answers before submitting a form?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would recommend:

1. Add a final page to your form called Review (or something similar).
2. On this page, insert a Content field. Content fields allow you to insert field data, so you can easily list out all of the user's answers in a concise format:

[image]

3. Underneath your content field, add a Yes/No field set to required. This way, the user must confirm that they've reviewed their answers before submitting their form.

Comment: If there are table fields in the form they can't be inserted, it appears, in a content field.

Comment: Correct; you cannot insert table field data directly into a Content field. However, you can use a Calculation field to target table field data (using an expression like '=Table.Select(FieldName)')  and then insert that Calculation field instead.